# syntax reading of python

Tags: python, while-loop

I was trying to understand the how actually python works as per syntax. 
So in an example:

```
x = 0

while x < 3:
    print("smaller")
    x = x + 1
```

of x < 3 it printed "smaller" three times. I agree it makes sense that it reads line by line and you are making the value of x go up by 1 after print statement as per syntax but I got really confused when i tried to change the order of syntax and as per my understanding it should've returned two "smaller" not three but it returned three"smaller".

```
x = 0
while x < 3:
    x = x + 1
    print("smaller")
```

Here, i defined x=0 and then loop function and then before print statement, i defined x=x+1 so, if python reads line by line it should return "smaller" two times only but it is returning three times. What is it that i am missing. Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Condiditon isn't checked on every statement - only at begining of loop.

Answer (score 0):

Condition is checked and then the code inside is executed entirely. So as long as the x value remains below 3

 `x = x + 1
 print("smaller")`

will be executed.

So the steps will be like
1) Check if value is less than 3
2) If yes, Then run the block of code inside while statement and If no,skip the while block.
3) Repeat step 1